# Subtract 40 minutes from current time

Tags: c++, qt, qdatetime

I would like to use QDateTime to represent the value of 40 minutes less than the current time as a string.

```
QDateTime time = QDateTime::currentDateTime() - QDateTime::fromString(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yy/MM/dd hh:40:00"), "yy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
```

I tried that. but, It's didn't working.

I want a string minus 40 minutes from the current time and date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QDateTime has an addSecs method. You can add `-40 * 60` seconds to effectively subtract 40 minutes.